# Find all columns that return unique rows from table in snowflake

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Is there any way to achieve this?

I am working on snowflake tables and for most of them primary key is not defined in ddl. And also since the primary key is not enforced in snowflake, it has duplicate records.

Is there any way to get all the columns name that fetches unique records.

My tables has more than 30 columns and to identify the columns that returns unique rows is a troublesome task as I have to check by distinct column name and then matching it total number of rows present in table.

For eg. Total number of rows count(*) = 50

It has col - 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

- Distinct of col 1 returns 20 rows
- Distinct of col1, col2 returns 30
- Distinct of col1, col2, col7 returns 50 rows

I have to manually take the columns name and then match it with total records.

Is there any way I can get the column name without checking each column or column combination one by one?

It would be great help if someone can guide me on this.

Comment: You have tags for two different DMBS, Snowflake and MySQL. In which one are you attempting to do this?

Comment: @GregPavlik - Snowflake.

Comment: Have you considered adding a column with an MD5 on a null-safe concatenation of all columns?

Comment: @GregPavlik, These tables are running in production, I can not alter them.

Comment: By "cannot alter them" are you referring to the source system? If so, that's okay. You can add an MD5 in the ETL/ELT pipeline or have Snowflake add it as a transformation from a landing table to a transformed table. If you can't alter the tables in Snowflake, that's another matter.

Comment: @GregPavlik, I cannot do that. That is not in my hand. My task is just to identify the unique columns without modifying anything in the current process.

Comment: Firstly, if you have duplicate records present, then no combination of attributes will generate a unique count of rows - even all columns will show a distinct row count > 1.  Secondly, without a PK definition, a brute force approach to looking for combinations of columns that result in unique rows may not be deterministic.  Let’s say you have a table that contains a date field, and just by coincidence there’s only 1 row per date *but* the business logic absolutely allows for multiple rows with the same date.  I would suggest working with your data owner to remove duplicates, and define PKs.

Comment: @JimDemitriou, how to enforce primary key in snowflake?

Comment: At present, they are not enforceable through a PK constraint, however if you define PKs on all tables, you can use that information to implement design patterns in your ETL/ELT or through streams and tasks to address duplicates (prevent prospectively or remove retrospectively).  Also, by ensuring you columns used in PKs defined as NOT NULL, the NOT NULL constraint will be enforced in Snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple way I can think of, but you could start running a query like this one:

```
SELECT column1, column2, count(*)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If this returns results, add another column:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, count(*)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY 1,2,3
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Repeat until the query returns zero results, that means you now have a unique combination.

However, note that this does NOT guarantee that combination will remain unique over time, nor that this is the only unique combination of columns in the data.You will need a deeper understanding of the data and it's source to find a truly unique key, if one exists.

Comment: Thank you @Nathan for suggestion. However this is time consuming as well. Please do let me know if you've some other logic.

Comment: There is no simple way to do what you are asking and as noted even the approach above may not be reliable. As others have noted in the comments it's entirely possible that the data does not contain any primary key or unique combination of values. The best approach is to work with whoever supplies the data to try and understand it's structure and logic.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your requirement is to get unique rows from the source table which has duplicate rows (no primary keys), if yes, you can use a merge statement.

1. Uniqueness of rows can be achieved using a Merge statement
   It's advised to use MERGE to process each record differently based on the DML kind
   https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html#merge

Example:
Here we are assuming lets say if you have any duplicate data in the source table, we will be using a merge statement with a temporary table and the merge will be on the hash key for each row between target table and source table and if there is no match, then only it will insert the row into target table.

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tgt_tb;

create or replace temp table tgt_tb
(id int, name string);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS src_tb;
create temp table src_tb
(id int, name string);

insert into src_tb
select 1,'a'
union all
select 1,'a'
union all
select 2,'b'
union all
select 3,'c';

insert into tgt_tb
select 3,'c';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS src_stg_tb;
create temp table src_stg_tb
as
select * from

(select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hash(*) order by hash(*) ) as rnm, hash(*) as hashkey
from src_tb
) A
where A.rnm=1;

merge into tgt_tb TGT
using src_stg_tb SRC
on hash(tgt.id, tgt.name) = SRC.hashkey
when not matched then insert
Values (src.id,src.name)

--select * from tgt_tb;
With MERGE you can specify “WHEN MATCHED” and “WHEN NOT MATCHED”. For just inserting new data, we use a MERGE statement with JUST a “WHEN NOT MATCHED” clause.

Regards,
Sujan